# How do I convert a linq expression to Azure Table Filter String in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, linq, azure, .net-core, azure-table-storage

I want to convert a linq expression to Azure Table Filter String in .NET Core

I am not familiar with working with query strings. So I prefer to use Linq to query the entities in Table Storage. This is working fine in .net framework with

```
table.CreateQuery<T>().AsQueryable().Where(expression).ToList();
```

The same functionality is not available in .net core or standard. So I want to have a helper method or statement that will convert the linq expression to a filter string which I can use to search entities in the Azure Table. Below is my code snippet of the method I want to use to search using the query expression. All I want is to convert the query expression to a filter string so that I can achieve the equivalent to

```
table.CreateQuery<T>().AsQueryable().Where(expression)
```

in .net framework.

```
        public static List<T> SearchEntities<T>(string table_name, Expression<Func<T, bool>> linq_expression) where T : ITableEntity, new()
        {
            var cloud_table = GetCloudTable(table_name); //Gets the CloudTable instance of the table
            string filter_string = string.Empty; //Convert the expression to filter string. This line is supposed to convert the linq_expression to a filter string. It can be a method call
            var query = new TableQuery<T>();
            query.FilterString = filter_string; //Set the filter string to the one that I have generated
            List<T> retrieved_entities = new List<T>();
            TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
            do
            {
                var response = cloud_table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, continuationToken).Result;//Gets the response from the Azure Table Storage
                var results = response.ToList();
                retrieved_entities.AddRange(results);//Adds the entities to the retrieved results
                continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
            } while (continuationToken != null);
            return retrieved_entities;
        }
```

Any kind of insight / advice on this is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install the package [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table) as per this [azure table doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2FTOC.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#install-the-required-nuget-package).

Then in your code, you can use `TableQuery.CombineFilters` and `TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition` to generate the filter string.

A simple example as below, you can modify it as per your need:

```
    //other code

    string filter_string = string.Empty;

    TableQuery<T> query = new TableQuery<T>();            

    string myfilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "xxx"),
                                                TableOperators.And,                                                   
                                                TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Email", QueryComparisons.Equal, "xxx@hotmail.com"));

    query.FilterString = myfilter;


    //other code
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan for this. However, I want to generate the value of myfilter variable from the Linq expression parsed as indicated in the code snippet I posted. Your code is not generating the filter from the Linq expression. It's rather generating the filter string from filter conditions. I want to generate the filter string from the Linq expression